# Subquery in JPQL (multiple select)

Tags: java, postgresql, jpql

I have deux tables in my datables. The `Account` table and the `AccountType` table. I need a JPQL query to retrieve all accounts with column kind (in table `AccountType`) equal "BalanceSheet", I also need another one to retrieve all accounts witch the column kind(in table AccountType) equal "Outturn".

I try this put the don't works.

```
Query query = daoFactory
            .getEntityManager()
            .createQuery(
                    "SELECT a FROM Account a WHERE a.deleted=false AND a.type_id IN (SELECT id FROM "
                    + "AccountType WHERE deleted=false AND kind='BalanceSheet')");
List<Account> result = query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to give a `identification variable` to your `AccountType` entity.

```
SELECT a 
  FROM Account a 
 WHERE a.deleted=false 
   AND a.type_id IN (SELECT at.id FROM AccountType at
                      WHERE at.deleted=false 
                        AND at.kind= 'BalanceSheet')
```

See also:

- [JPQL example - Oracle JEE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtl.html) (Just to understand the basics)